# How to merge custom login (Email) with Facebook login in swift using firebase

Tags: swift, facebook, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am implementing custom (Email) and Facebook login authentication in swift using Firebase. Since, I enabled multiple accounts per email address, a same user using his email as well as his facebook account can sign in to the app. Firebase considers them as two separate users, but I want to merge them as long as the email address is same. I found this 
[link from the Facebook site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers#associating) which explain the scenario which i am trying to solve. I am looking for any code samples on how to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple with Firebase. The below code should work and I have also included a link to the documentation describing the process.

```
let credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: 
FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString)

if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
   user.link(with: credential) { (user, error) in
      //perform any actions after the account has been linked
   }
}
```

Here is a link to the Firebase documentation on the subject:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure how this merges my two individual accounts. 
I tried the code (even I am aware of the link) which you mentioned. I still see as two individual accounts. It mentions that you can link the accounts, does that mean merge?