# Firebase Multiple Auth Providers Issue

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, twitter, firebase-authentication

I've been banging my head and keyboard Googling, reading the Firebase docs and combing StackOverflow for days now for similar situations and help.

Here's the situation:

1. User logs into iOS app using Twitter button.
2. User signs out (for whatever reason).
3. Some time later, the User returns to the app and taps the Facebook button, and Firebase returns the following error:

> "Auth error: An account already exists with the same email address but
>   different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated
>   with this email address."

The Firebase docs say to link the user to, in this case, to the Facebook credential. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking

```
user.link(with: credential) { (user, error) in
```

But at this point, `Auth.auth().currentUser == nil` so there is no account to link to. Furthermore, the "One account per email address" setting is set to TRUE.

From Auth: `signInAndRetrieveData(with credential: AuthCredential, completion: FirebaseAuth.AuthDataResultCallback? = nil)`

> FIRAuthErrorCodeAccountExistsWithDifferentCredential - Indicates the
>   email asserted by the credential (e.g. the email in a Facebook access
>   token) is already in use by an existing account, that cannot be
>   authenticated with this sign-in method. Call fetchProvidersForEmail
>   for this user’s email and then prompt them to sign in with any of the
>   sign-in providers returned. This error will only be thrown if the "One
>   account per email address" setting is enabled in the Firebase console,
>   under Auth settings.

So back to this situation (user currently has Twitter credential, user has tapped Facebook button, **currentUser == nil** and the above error exists), at this point, would it be appropriate to call the Twitter sign-in function programmatically (on behalf of the user) and then link the Facebook credential to this current user?

Has someone come across this situation and solved it for a cool user experience instead of kicking out an alert to tap twitter button?

Thank you for the help

Comment: I had a similar question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44039462/how-to-merge-custom-login-email-with-facebook-login-in-swift-using-firebase

Comment: So... uh... dumb question, but did you turn off the "One account per email address" setting in the Firebase console? It's down in the "Sign-in method" tab, in the Advanced section.

Comment: Thanks for the question. I've tested the "One account per email address" on both options. With the option OFF, a new account with the same email address is created which does not work well with the app and could be programmatic. The option is ON and the above situation plays, and the user is not authorized, therefore the user cannot access the app's data.

Comment: Thank you Vira. In the case that the user signed out, there is no Auth.auth().currentUser to link to

Comment: Have you got this solved? I am facing a similar problem and mine is a little bit more complicated..At least you know in your case you need to log-in Twitter first but in mine I dont even know whether Twitter or Email-Password to log-in.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345277/how-to-correctly-link-different-auth-accounts-in-firebase-ios

Comment: I can't say that I solved it permanently (I will seek to do that as part of my next upgrade). So for a short-term fix, I recorded the users initial login method in UserDefaults (e.g. Facebook, Twitter, Google - I didn't use email/password). On subsequent logins, I would only present the option they initially logged in if the login prompt is presented again. Usually the user remains logged in so this login prompt is only presented if they log out for some reason. It's a band-aid solution but works for me now. Good luck